# Tableview Row Height in Size Inspector is overriding cell for row height datasource

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a code that defines the row height of each table view cell. However, the row height defined in Size Inspector is overriding everything. What should I do?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return CGFloat(81.0)
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        return CGFloat(212.0)
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        return CGFloat(127.0)
    } else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        return CGFloat(147.0)
    } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
        return CGFloat(63.0)
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: try implementing `heightForRowAt` instead of `estimatedHeightForRowAt`. Also, make you life easier by putting this mapping into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the estimatedRowHeights not the actual row heights.

You want to write:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        return CGFloat(81.0)
    case 1:
        return CGFloat(212.0)
    case 2:
        return CGFloat(127.0)
    case 3:
        return CGFloat(147.0)
    case 4;
        return CGFloat(63.0)
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

not `estimatedHeight...`

Comment: I've tried that as well, that was my original code. But For some reason the Size Inspector defined row height is also overriding the height defined in datasource.